# Can reduce return an array of 2 values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, higher-order-functions

So i'm trying to do a js challenge that i have to sum the even indexes numbers in the index 0 of an x array and the odd indexes on the 1 index of the x array, i used map but i'm feeling that it could be better as i'm using an external array to return and map already returns a new array, my solution:

```
    //  write code here.
    const sumOfArr = [0, 0];
    array.map((num, i) => {
        return i % 2 === 0 ? sumOfArr[0] += num : sumOfArr[1] += num
    });
    return sumOfArr
}
const nums = [50, 60, 60, 45, 70];
const result = alternatingSums(nums);
console.log("result: ", result);
expect(result).toEqual([180, 105]);
```

and i also tried with reduce but it always return NaN:

```
return array.reduce((acc, num, i) => {
        console.log(acc, '---', num, '---', i)
        return i % 2 === 0 ? acc[0] = acc[0] + num : acc[1] = acc[1] num
    }, [0, 0]);
```

I spend my whole morning trying the spot my mistake with the reduce as it seems that i just need to *reduce* the array to a smaller one.

Comment: You need to do the assignment first and then just `return acc;` and not return the entire expression

Comment: Yep, doing the assignment and returning just the acc works just fine :s, missed this detail, thx!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
function alternatingSums(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, n, i) => {
    acc[i % 2] += n;
    return acc;
  }, [0, 0]);
}

const nums = [50, 60, 60, 45, 70];
const result = alternatingSums(nums);
console.log("result: ", result); // [180, 105]
```

Comment: This solution is expected to be [180, 105], i think it is getting it wrong on the index 1 and it's doing 0,5 as 0 so it goes on the index 0 of the new arr, but is an interesting way to do

Comment: Yes, I misread. I fixed it. I thought `n` was supposed to be checked for oddness, instead of `i`

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the accumulator

```js
function alternatingSums(array) {
  return array.reduce((acc, num, i) => {
    i % 2 === 0 ? acc[0] = acc[0] + num : acc[1] = acc[1] + num; // changed here
    return acc; // changed here
  }, [0, 0]);
}
const nums = [50, 60, 60, 45, 70];
const result = alternatingSums(nums);
console.log("result: ", result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is with:

```
return i % 2 === 0 ? acc[0] = acc[0] + num : acc[1] = acc[1] num
```

On the very first iteration, it will return a number, not an array, since `acc[0] = acc[0] + num` will return the assigned value (ie: whatever is to the right of the assignment operator `=`), in this case, `acc[0] + num` (or `acc[1] + num` in the other case). This results in subsequent calls of `acc[0]` and `acc[1]` giving `undefined`, since a number doesn't have such properties.

Instead, you need to return a modified array each time. One possible way of doing this is by [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the array of the accumulator in the reduce callback and then adding return a new array, with the modified components:

```js
function alternatingSums(array) {
  return array.reduce(([even, odd], num, i) => {
    return i % 2 === 0 ? [even+num, odd] : [even, odd+num];
  }, [0, 0]);
}

const nums = [50, 60, 60, 45, 70];
const result = alternatingSums(nums);
console.log(result); // [180, 105]);
```

Comment: That's very interesting, i completely forgot you could destructur arrays, thx

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `acc` only after the operation `i % 2 === 0 ? acc[0] = acc[0] + num : acc[1] = acc[1] + num;`

```js
function alternateIndexSums(array) {
  return array.reduce((acc, num, i) => {
    i % 2 === 0 ? acc[0] = acc[0] + num : acc[1] = acc[1] + num;
    return acc;
  }, [0, 0]);
}

let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
console.log(alternateIndexSums(myArray));
```